# What is the equivalent in PyQt5 for "PySide.QtWebKit"?

Tags: python

I bought a book (Learning Python with Raspberry pi - Alex Brandbury and Ben Everard) that uses **PySide** to teach Python, but it seems **Python3** is no longer combative to PySide, so the alternative seems to be Qt5.

How can I adapt this code below to PyQt5?

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *

class Browser(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()

        self.webview = QWebView(self)
        self.webview.load("http://www.google.com")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600)

        self.back_btn = QPushButton("<", self)
        self.back_btn.clicked.connect(self.webview.back)
        self.back_btn.setMaximumSize(20,20)

        self.forward_btn = QPushButton(">", self)
        self.forward_btn.clicked.connect(self.webview.forward)
        self.forward_btn.setMaximumSize(20,20)

        self.url_entry = QLineEdit(self)
        self.url_entry.setMinimumSize(200,20)
        self.url_entry.setMaximumSize(300,20)

        self.go_btn = QPushButton("Go", self)
        self.go_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_btn_clicked)
        self.go_btn.setMaximumSize(20,20)

        self.favourites = QComboBox(self)
        self.favourites.addItems(["http://www.google.com", 
                                  "http://www.raspberrypi.org", 
                                  "http://docs.python.org/3/"])
        self.favourites.activated.connect(self.favourite_selected)
        self.favourites.setMinimumSize(200,20)
        self.favourites.setMaximumSize(300,20)

        self.search_box = QLineEdit(self)
        self.search_box.setMinimumSize(200,20)
        self.search_box.setMaximumSize(300,20)

        self.search_btn = QPushButton("Search", self)
        self.search_btn.clicked.connect(self.search_btn_clicked)
        self.search_btn.setMaximumSize(50,20)

        self.zoom_slider = QSlider(Qt.Orientation(1),self)
        self.zoom_slider.setRange(2, 50)
        self.zoom_slider.setValue(10)
        self.zoom_slider.valueChanged.connect(self.zoom_changed)

        self.zoom_label = QLabel("Zoom:")
        self.webview.loadStarted.connect(self.page_loading)

        self.menu_bar = QHBoxLayout()
        self.menu_bar.addWidget(self.back_btn)
        self.menu_bar.addWidget(self.forward_btn)
        self.menu_bar.addWidget(self.url_entry)
        self.menu_bar.addWidget(self.go_btn)
        self.menu_bar.addStretch()
        self.menu_bar.addWidget(self.favourites)
        self.menu_bar.addStretch()
        self.menu_bar.addWidget(self.search_box)
        self.menu_bar.addWidget(self.search_btn)
        self.menu_bar.addWidget(self.zoom_label)
        self.menu_bar.addWidget(self.zoom_slider)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.menu_bar)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.webview)

        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    def go_btn_clicked(self):
        self.webview.load(self.url_entry.text())

    def favourite_selected(self):
        self.webview.load(self.favourites.currentText())

    def zoom_changed(self):
        self.webview.setZoomFactor(self.zoom_slider.value()/10)

    def search_btn_clicked(self):
        self.webview.load("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + self.search_box.text())

    def page_loading(self):   
        self.url_entry.setText(self.webview.url().toString())



class BrowserWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BrowserWindow, self).__init__()      
        self.widget = Browser()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.openFile = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), 'Open', self)
        self.openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.openFile.setStatusTip('Open new File')
        self.openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        self.menu = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = self.menu.addMenu('&File')
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.openFile)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)

    def showDialog(self):
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',
                    '/home')
        self.widget.webview.load("file:///"+fname)


# Create a Qt application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = BrowserWindow()
window.show()

# Enter Qt application main loop
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

I tried that, but a get an error class Browser(QWidget):
NameError: name 'QWidget' is not defined

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class Browser(QWidget):
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "QtWidgets.QWidget"

Because we are running this program using PyQt5 and the widgets it includes you need to notify your code to pull all of these QWidgets from the QtWidgets module.

Hope this helps!